# Showing that a function with multiple components does not uniformly converge.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, solution-verification

I am working on some problems from an analysis book for self study to get a better idea of uniform convergence, and I am having a hard time visualizing what this function looks like, or really understanding if I am doing this correctly.

I am trying to show that the sequence of functions
$$
\gamma_n(t) = \bigg(\frac{1}{1+nt}, \frac{t}{n}\bigg)
$$

does not uniformly converge on [0,1]. The way I have done this is to show that the limit function (as $n\to\infty$) looks like this.
$$
F(t) = 
\begin{cases} (1,0) \text{ if } t=0\\
(0,0) \text{ if } t \neq 0
\end{cases}.
$$
Since the limit function is discontinuous, then this function cannot uniformly converge as there does not an exist an $n>N$ such that
$$
||\gamma_n(t) - F(t)|| < \epsilon \text{ for all } t\in [0,1].
$$

Is this the correct way about showing uniform convergence for these functions with multiple components? I feel like I don't quite understand what this type of function looks like, other than the final function is piecewise and therefore not continuous.

Comment: What is a function with multiple components? Also, your sentence, "then this function cannot uniformly converge ... " is just terrible.

Comment: @TedShifrin In this case it seems that the $\gamma_n$ are functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Math1000: Oh, a vector-valued function is what the OP meant. Perhaps.

Comment: A sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly has a continuous limit function. So if you have a sequence of continuous functions that converges to a function that is not continuous, then the convergence cannot be uniform. There isn't really anything more to be said.